# Check whether enum in Swift belongs to a constant set

Tags: swift, enums, logical-operators

Is there special syntax in Swift for checking whether an enum belongs into a constant set? What I have in mind is something like

```
status in (.Active, .Matching)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded by now that (unfortunately) there is now special syntax for this case.

Comment: I don't think it's unfortunate - it's fortunate that there isn't special syntax for everything.